# How to print values into next empty row cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I have designed a VBA form to collect data from the user. However, I want to allow the user to fill the form multiple times and each time prints the filled out data into appropriate cells in the Excel sheet, so I want the VBA program to look for the next empty cell in the sheet without having the user to look manually and select it.

```
Cells(lastRow, 1) = emplName
Cells(lastRow, 2) = depTxt
Cells(lastRow, 3) = emplNo
Cells(lastRow, 4) = mngrName
Cells(lastRow, 5) = ComboBox1.Value
```

Here for instance, these five values should then print into the first row, if the form is used again, it should find the next empty row to print the values.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  The code you have is a good start,but your question is asking the SO community to write the code for you.  I would start by researching loops and possibly arrays to get to your goal.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways to select/detect last row in Excel with VBA. The best one I usually use:

```
Function LastRow(wsName As String, Optional columnToCheck As Long = 1) As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets(wsName)
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, columnToCheck).End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```

This is how to use it for column "E" (5th column):

`someLastRow = LastRow("WorksheetName", 5)`

If you have ideas for improvement, feel free to make PR: https://github.com/Vitosh/VBA_personal/blob/master/LastThings.vb