# Click submit in userform to fill data in next row

Tags: excel, vba, range, row, userform

I created a userform.

If I click submit I get next cell selected. When I run the userform again data are pasted into the same cells like before.

This is VBA part of the "submit" command on the userform:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Sheets("Test").Range("A2").value = TextBox3.value
    Sheets("Test").Range("B2").value = TextBox4.Text
    Sheets("Test").Range("C2").value = TextBox5.Text
    Sheets("Test").Range("D2").value = TextBox6.Text
    Sheets("Test").Range("E2").value = ComboBox1.Text
    
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

I need when I press submit to go to next row and paste all data from userform.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59078104/how-to-print-values-into-next-empty-row-cells) help? Further [reading here](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, please. In the way you presented your data, it looks that the columns (from A to E) have the same number of rows. If not, you must calculate `lastRow` before filling data in each column:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
  Dim sh As workseet, lastRow As Long
  Set sh = Sheets("Test") 'it would be better to fully define it (workbook included)
  lastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    sh.Range("A" & lastRow).value = TextBox3.value
    sh.Range("B" & lastRow).value = TextBox4.text
    sh.Range("C" & lastRow).value = TextBox5.text
    sh.Range("D" & lastRow).value = TextBox6.text
    sh.Range("E" & lastRow).value = ComboBox1.value

    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi FaneDuru, I changed to a worksheet and added these lines you suggested and it is working. I will have to add more lines but it will be same like these ones here. Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: @Dino Blažević : Glad I was able to help! But we here, in case of a piece of code which answers the question, we tick the left code side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. If somebody else search for something similar, he will know that the answer does what needed...